# Why is the book using the equation of $\Delta t$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time-dilation

I have a question on a worked out example from a text book. The example is as follows.

> A proposed plane would carry intercontinental travelers at speeds many times those of today’s fastest airliners. Imagine that such a plane is 50 m long (when parked) and cruises at 6000 m/s (13,400 mi/h, or about Mach 18). At precisely noon, it passes over Los Angeles, and an observer on the ground with exceptional eyesight peers through its window. He sees that the clock inside also reads precisely noon.
>
> (a) How long is the moving plane according to this observer?
>
> (b) Later, a ground observer in Seattle, 1600 km north, checks the plane’s clock as it passes overhead. By how much does the reading differ from that on her watch?

My confusion is with part 2 of the question. It asks for the change in time between the clock in the ship and the clock of the observer.
The book solves the problem like this,

> The ground observers watch a single clock ticking off events at the same location in the plane’s frame, so this clock registers the proper time $\Delta t_0 $, and the
> time passing on their own watches is the longer $\Delta t$. We calculate $\Delta t$ in the
> usual classical way, because both it and the 1600 km are according to the same
> (ground) observers.

The book then uses the value of $\Delta t$ and then plugs it in the equation $\Delta t'=\frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}$. My issue with the solution is that I don't know why we're using this particular equation. $\Delta t'= t'_2-t'_1$ and both $t$ primes are in the same space that we call $S'$ or just the space in which the ship is at rest. But the question is asking FOR the change in time from the observers perspective and the clock in side the ship, so that means we calculate the change between $t'$ and $ t$(I might be misunderstanding the question) so shouldn't the equation be $t-t'$ which is a different equation than $\Delta t'$.

Comment: Yes, your book is being careless with its wording. You don't say what the book is, but it is not being rigorous if it just throws factors of $\gamma$ around in the way you decribe. The question should be answered using the Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the plane passes, synchronize the clocks. This is time $t_1 = t_1'$.  Special Relativity allows for this. Assume the clocks on the ground are synchronized too.

Your question assumes such a synchronization.

"At precisely noon, it passes over Los Angeles.. He sees that the clock inside also reads precisely noon." Therefore, $t_1'=t_1$.

$\Delta t= t_2-t_1$

and

$t_2=\Delta t + t_1 $

$\Delta t'= t'_2-t'_1 = \frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}$

$t_2' = \frac{1}{\gamma}\Delta t +  t_1' = \frac{1}{\gamma} \Delta t +t_1 $

$t_2' - t_2 = \frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}$